# All browsers incredibly slow except... opera?

Tags: windows, browser

For the past week, Chrome and Fierfox have become so slow that they often time out. Mean while, Opera continues to work flawlessly. I simply don't understand why nor do I have an idea to to even begin troubleshoot this.

I'm running win 7 and latest versions of all browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is embarrassing but I had enabled proxy usage in IE which of course Fx and Chrome picked up!
Oh Opera, once again you show why you simply rock :)

Comment: Err.. so Firefox and Chrome have a good compatability feature which migrates proxy settings from IE, and opera does not, so you blame the other browsers? Doesn't make sense to me :/

Comment: FireFox and Chrome ask the OS for proxy information; Opera tends to look after this itself. IE, of course, regards the OS proxy settings as its own. That said, you can tell FireFox to *not* look at the OS settings.